# Count how many sections in a article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At least i want to count  how many sections are in one article. If this doesn´t work with this elements, I also could use normal "div" tags instead.
Sorry for my bad english.

```
<article>
    <section>
        <p>text</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>example</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: `var count = $('article section').length;`

Comment: `var count = $('article').find('section').length;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$("article section").length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     <div>
         <p></p>
         <p></p>
         <p></p>
         <p></p>
         <p></p>
     </div>
```

script:

```
     var a=$("div p").length;
     alert(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one `<article>` and are wanting to know how many are in each one:

```
$('article').each(function(){
   var secCount = $(this).find('section').length;
});
```